# Why does my studio flash fire when another photographer takes a picture?

Tags: wireless-flash, strobes

Last night I was at the event with my friend. I operated a photobooth with studio flash trigger strobes RT-04, and my friend had photo coverage of the event. Every time my friend took a photo the studio flash also fired. He is using Canon 6D with Speedlite 580EXII.

Please help me to figure out how to not fire the studio flash when my friend takes pictures. The pictures on my photobooth turned out black when we were doing photobooth and photo coverage at the same time.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Godox RT-04 are radio frequency (RF) based transmitters/receivers. It is unlikely that your friend triggered your studio strobes over RF unless he used a similar transmitter and the same channel setting.

However many studio strobes have a photo cell, which lets them spot a nearby flash. The studio strobe will then fire to synchronize to that particular flash (e.g. from your friend). This is called optical triggering. Depending on your studio strobes, there could be a button or setting to disable optical triggering. You can always disable this behaviour by covering the photo cell, so that no light will reach it.   Try this with your friend before the next event, to see if that solves your problem.

Comment: With the Godox it is a mode you choose. The OP should know how he did set up his photo booth.